Gradle Error in expo application building
I encountered such an error while creating the apk file of the expo project. How can I fix it?
enter image description here
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-permissions'.

Could not set unknown property 'classifier' for task ':expo-permissions:androidSourcesJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.

I tried all the ways but it still didn't help
